# implementation of the Shrinking Ball algorithm to construct the Medial Axis Transform

Tags: python

I wanted to run the code in the link below, but unfortunately, when running compute-ma.py, I get an error not found module masbpy and the module is not installed in Anaconda, conda command not found.
Can you guide me what to do?
[text](https://github.com/tudelft3d/masbpy)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tN7B3.png)

I have installed all the dependencies mentioned in the usage section
But I have a problem with the installation masbpy

Comment: You can certainly do `pip install` with that string, assuming you can figure out how to get that into your conda environment.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you show your effort and submit data to be used to reproduce your problem. While providing an image is helpful, it doesn't allow for reproducing the issue. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.